# have same window in every muitiple document window

Tags: mfc

I use five mdichildwnd to show in my MFC app, every midchildwnd have a window A, can I use window A as a Single Instance? or have a better solution?

Comment: Your question is not clear: how could you have a "Single Instance" in five different windows? You'd need at least five of them...

Comment: the sigle instance wnd in only one MDI is ok, the othe MDI's event response in the sigle instance wnd is fail.